# Powershell send directory contents to a program

Tags: powershell, foreach, executable, get-childitem

My goal is to translate .wav files in a directory using an executable which converts them to the proper audio format. Once these files are created, I then need to move everything out of the directory to another directory destination.  What should happen is once the file executes the program (CommandLineConverter.exe) creates a new file in the correct audio format.

I tried Get-ChildItem pointing to the executable. Early on I ran into problems with the script accepting (x86).  However, that seems resolved now and I don't any errors on debugging.  The Move-Item is commented out for now because I'm trying to get the files to convert.  Currently the script is not converting the files.  There is no output that I can see.

I considered as an alternative just opening every item in the directory ($path) as I set the default for wave files to open in the CommandLineConverter.exe; however, that script didn't go well either.

Anyway here is the script that I have so far for sending directory contents to the executable which does not appear to be working as intended.  Any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
$path= "C:\Execuscribe\ExecuDropBox\Dropbox (ExecuScribe)\Conduent\Verizon"
$destination= "C:\Execuscribe\ExecuDropBox\Dropbox (ExecuScribe)\Converted"
Get-ChildItem $path | ForEach-Object 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Verint\Playback\CommandLineConvertor.exe'
#   {
        
 #       Move-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $Destination
#    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kirk,

I think you want something along this line:

```
$path= "C:\Execuscribe\ExecuDropBox\Dropbox (ExecuScribe)\Conduent\Verizon"
$destination= "C:\Execuscribe\ExecuDropBox\Dropbox (ExecuScribe)\Converted"
Get-ChildItem $path  -Filter "*.wav" | 
ForEach-Object {
   &  'C:\Program Files (x86)\Verint\Playback\CommandLineConvertor.exe' $($_.FullName)

  $MIArgs = @{Path = $($_.fullname) 
              Destination = "$Destination"}
   Move-Item @MIArgs
}
```

Add the -Filter parameter to Get-ChildItem to only retrieve .wav files.
Call the program specifying each file as it comes down the pipe. I don't know how the converter's arguments are specified but the code included just contains the fully qualified filename you can add any identifiers that are required.
Copy the converted file to the new location you'll have to replace NewExt with the output extension of the converted file.

This is untested code!

Comment: Holy Cow RetiredGeek!  You are some kind of genius.  The conversion works.  I commented out the move function for now.  The conversion doesn't change the extension.  What happens is it renames the file by adding _Conv.wav

Comment: I assume I just replace .NewExt then with .wav since the file extension isn't changed.

Comment: I just uncommented the move function and there is an error.  Conversion works but moving items out of the directory to destination does not work.  The error appears to be too long to post in this answer.  Basically it is saying cannot find path .wav because it does not exist

Comment: Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Execuscribe\ExecuApp\Convertwave5.ps1:6 char:39

Comment: Move-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\execuboss\.wav' because it does not exist.
At C:\Execuscribe\ExecuApp\Convertwave5.ps1:8 char:1

Comment: Kirk, since your program doesn't change the filetype you don't need to adjust the filename. I changed the Answer to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

[RetiredGeek's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71728414/45375) contains the crucial pointer:

- You must place the call to your executable inside a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) passed to [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) ...
- ... and, because the executable's path is (of necessity) *quoted*, you must invoke via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-).
- Additionally, you must pass each input file's full path as an *explicit argument* to your executable, via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_), which reflects the pipeline input object at hand.

  - In *Windows PowerShell*, you must use `$_.FullName` to ensure that the input file's *full path* is passed; fortunately, this is no longer necessary in [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), where just `$_` is enough.

However, with respect to the renaming part, I suggest retrieving the conversion's output file via [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item), which you can then pipe to a single [`Move-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item) call placed in a new, final pipeline segment:

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $path | ForEach-Object { 
  & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Verint\Playback\CommandLineConvertor.exe' $_.FullName  
  Get-Item -LiteralPath (Join-Path $_.DirectoryName ($_.BaseName + '_Conv.wav'))
} | Move-Item -Destination $destination
```

Note:

- `-LiteralPath` is used for robustness, to ensure that all paths are treated *literally* rather than as [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards), as would happen if you used `-Path` instead (which may be positionally *implied*, such as in your `Get-ChildItem $path` call).
- `$_.DirectoryName` is the input file's *directory* path. `$_.BaseName + '_Conv.wav'` takes the input file name's base name (the file name without its extension) and appends `_Conv.wav` to identify the conversion output file name. The two pieces of information are then joined with [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) to form the output file's full path.
- Note that passing the conversion output file path to `Get-Item -LiteralPath` isn't strictly necessary, but it again ensures binding to (`Move-Item`'s) `-LiteralPath` parameter. While `Move-Item` also accepts path *strings* as pipeline input, they bind to the `-Path` parameter, and are therefore again subject to interpretation as wildcard expressions, which notably would cause failures with literal paths containing `[` characters (e.g., `file[1].wav`).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved mostly with RetiredGeek's code and advice.  The only issue with this code was that the converted files remained in the source directory or $path.  I added another backup directory and sent unconverted files to backup and using mklement0's code was able to get the converted files over to the Converted directory.

```
$path= "C:\Execuscribe\ExecuDropBox\Dropbox (ExecuScribe)\Conduent\Verizon"
$destination= "C:\Execuscribe\ExecuDropBox\Dropbox (ExecuScribe)\Converted"
$backup= "C:\Execuscribe\ExecuDropBox\Dropbox (ExecuScribe)\Backup"
Get-ChildItem $path  -Filter "*.wav" | 
ForEach-Object {
   &  'C:\Program Files (x86)\Verint\Playback\CommandLineConvertor.exe' $($_.FullName)

$MIArgs = @{Path = $($_.fullname) 
            Destination = "$backup"}
   Move-Item @MIArgs

   Get-Item (Join-Path $_.DirectoryName ($_.BaseName + '_Conv.wav'))
  } | Move-Item -Destination $destination
```